# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException

Tags: java, jpa, testing, ejb, persistence

I've tried to run a test like this in my project, but there is always one error as above in title. I've already read answers, that I should add provider or resources or change the location of the `persistence.xml` but the location is fine and it doesn't help!

```
public class Test {
    private static final String DEFAULT_USER_STATUS = "registered";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JFPersistenceUnit");
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        Status e3 = entityManager.find(Status.class, 1);
        System.out.println(e3.getStatusName());

        Status status = (Status)entityManager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Status s WHERE s.statusName =:status")
            .setParameter("status", DEFAULT_USER_STATUS)
            .getSingleResult();

        System.out.println(status.getStatusName());

        User user = (User)entityManager.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.nickName =:nickName")
            .setParameter("nickName", "teddy")
            .getSingleResult();

        System.out.println(user.getLastName());

        entityManager.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();
    }
}
```

the `persistence.xml` file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="JFPersistenceUnit" >
        <!--transaction-type="JTA" —>
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <!-jta-data-source>JFResources</jta-data-source-->
        <class>ru.javafiddle.jpa.entity.Access</class>
        <class>ru.javafiddle.jpa.entity.File</class>
        <class>ru.javafiddle.jpa.entity.Group</class>
        <class>ru.javafiddle.jpa.entity.Hash</class>
        <class>ru.javafiddle.jpa.entity.Library</class>
        <class>ru.javafiddle.jpa.entity.LibraryToProject</class>
        <class>ru.javafiddle.jpa.entity.Project</class>
        <class>ru.javafiddle.jpa.entity.User</class>
        <class>ru.javafiddle.jpa.entity.UserGroup</class>
        <class>ru.javafiddle.jpa.entity.Status</class>
        <class>ru.javafiddle.jpa.entity.Type</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties></properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

the `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ru.javafiddle.ejb</groupId>
<artifactId>JavaFiddle-ejb</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What can I do with all this stuff? The server is correctly deployed, I'm only trying to check the connection to my database and test some queries. The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    org/eclipse/persistence/exceptions/PersistenceUnitLoadingException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
at javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProviderResolverHolder$DefaultPersistenceProviderResolver.getPersistenceProviders(PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java:99)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:75)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
at Test.main(Test.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 13 more
```

It occurs in place of calling the function: createEntityManagerFactory("JFPersistenceUnit")

UPDATE: I have no idea why it is said, that is smth wrong with eclipse, when I'm using only hibernate.

Comment: Please check your hibernate-jpa.xxx.jar is available in the test project lib folder or please copy this jar to server lib folder. It says Class file not there.

Comment: Sudhakar, I have now hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final.jar and hibernate.jpa.-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar in my lib folder, I added them as libs in Project Structure.  But there is no effect . Among all hibernate-jpa.xxx.jar I found only this one.

Comment: You should add `eclipselink` as your database connection provider `<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>` and add the `eclipselink` dependency to your `pom.xml`: `<dependency>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
          <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
          <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
</dependency>`, as stated [here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/231508?tstart=0).